# Why IQueryOver has 2 type arguments?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, queryover

Why IQueryOver has 2 type arguments:

```
QueryOver<TRoot,TSubType> is an API for retrieving entities by composing
NHibernate.Criterion.Expression objects expressed using Lambda expression
syntax.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: to support fluent syntax, and have access to root settings all the time.

#### not so fluent

So we can use this definition:

```
IQueryOver<Contact,Contact> rootQuery = session  // here we have Contact query
    .QueryOver<Contact>();                          
IQueryOver<Contact, Employee> emplQueryOver = rootQuery
    .JoinQueryOver<Employee>(c => c.Parnter);       // here we work with its Parnter
IQueryOver<Contact, Employee> creatorQueryOver = emplQueryOver
    .JoinQueryOver<Employee>(e => e.Creator);       // here we have creator of Parnter
```

So having this, we can do some filtering:

```
emplQueryOver.Where(...
creatorQueryOver.Where(...
```

and then go back to root query and set

```
rootQuery.OrderBy(c => c.ID).Desc
    .ThenBy(c => c.LastName)
      .Asc
    .SelectList(...
    .Take(50);
```

#### fluent

But because of the interface `IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType>` beeing returned all the way down, we can do that without the middle variables... we can do it in one fluent run

```
var list = session  // here we have Contact query
    .QueryOver<Contact>()
       .Where(... //filter contact
    // Join Parnter
    .JoinQueryOver<Employee>(c => c.Parnter)
        .Where(... //filter Partner
    // Join More
    .JoinQueryOver<Employee>(e => e.Creator)

    // While still having the Root in the scope we can do
    .SelectList(list => list....
    .OrderBy(c => c.ID)
      .Desc
    .ThenBy(c => c.Code)
      .Asc
    .Take(50)
    .Skip(50)
    .List<Contact>(); // the Root
```